# How to count HTTP responses per web page using WebExtension

Tags: android, firefox-addon-webextensions, webexception

Using WebExtensions, I am trying to write a *content script* which would count the number of HTTP responses per web page.

I just started looking into WebExtensions, so I may be completely off the track, but so far my approach has been to modify the *background script* to listen to `browser.webRequest.onHeadersReceived`. Once fired, callback to that function would invoke `browser.tabs.sendMessage` to the `tabId` from where the request to this response originated.

In the *content script* I use `browser.runtime.onMessage.addListener` to listen to those messages from the background script.

With this approach I have two problems:

1. The background script is trying to send messages to the content script even *before* the content script has started listening, resulting in errors from the `sendMessage` and thus lost information.
2. On page reload, some of the messages from the background script are received *before* the content script is reloaded, some are lost (presumably during the period where one content script was unloaded and before another one started) and some are received after.

I've been looking whether `browser.storage.local` can help me with this situation. With this I can avoid the problem of messages being lost by simply keeping the count in that storage.

But I still have the problem in the background script that I don't know whether to increment the count for the web page that was displayed before the reload happened, or the one after (due to the problem #2 above).

I think instead of using `tabId` as a "pointer" to where the count is increased, having some kind of an `ID` for the web page to which the response belongs to would help. But I haven't been able to find anything like that in the documentation yet. But again, I'm novice to WebExtensions, so there may be a completely different approach I'm missing.

Comment: There could be several solutions depending on how you use that data in the end. So far it sounds like all you need is to add `"run_at": "document_start"` to your content script declaration. Alternatively you can accumulate the data in the background script's global variable e.g. `const data = {}` then in the webRequest listener you would update or add  `data[details.tabId]`. As for intercepting requests in the content script it'll be more convoluted.

Comment: @wOxxOm thanks, setting `"run_at": "document_start"` seems to be what I need (feel free to post it as answer, I'll do some more testing and likely accept it). I'm unsure about your second suggestion, the problem being that the background script doesn't know when the document is reloaded and so I don't know when to reset the accumulated data back to zero.

Comment: The background script can use browser.webNavigation API to detect page reloads. I think I've even seen an answer about that on SO.

Comment: You're right, I am able to reset the accumulated data in a callback passed to `browser.webNavigation.onBeforeNavigate.addListener`. I now prefer the second solution, thanks :)